# Joining 'with' clause result with a table when 'with' clause has no data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a query which has one with clause (view) and this is joined with a table using INNER/OUTER join. The issue is when the table doesn't have data, the join gets failed and no result is returned. However, the view has data.

I've used an INNER join which is failed in the first case. Then I tried with Left Outer Join which also doesn't work. Actually, the main query is quite complex, so I presented the problem in below code snippet. I'm expecting the answer in this format only

```
with myView as (Select mp.Id, sum(mp.Quantity) counts from Map mp where 
mp.bizDate='22-Jan-2019' group by mp.Id)

Select m.Id, mv.counts, (mv.counts - sum(m.Quantity)) from Map m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN myView mv ON 
m.id=mv.Id where m.bizDate='25-Jan-2019' group by m.Id, mv.counts
```

The issue is when Map table has no records it doesn't return any data, even if myView is having records. I need records in any case if one of them has data (either of myView or Map).

Sample Data:

Table: Map

```
Id          Quantity               BizDate
A            100                   22-Jan-2019
A            300                   22-Jan-2019
A            300                   25-Jan-2019
B            100                   22-Jan-2019
B            200                   25-Jan-2019
C            500                   22-Jan-2019
D            300                   25-Jan-2019
```

The Expected Output shoud be:

```
Id        Counts               (counts-Quantity)
A         400                       100         --> (400-300)
B         100                      -100         --> (100-200)
C         500                       500         --> (500-NA)
D         0                        -300         --> (NA-300)
```

Comment: Then use `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead.

Comment: That doesn't work. Since Map has no data in it, m.id=mv.tuneID join fails and that's why it doesn't return the result. But if myView has no data and Map has data the result displayed with OUTER Joins.

Comment: Sounds like you MIGHT want to use some form of a union rather than a join?  This link is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458145/sql-check-if-data-exists-on-either-table

Comment: Probably your WHERE clause is turning your outer join into an inner join.   Can't say since you don't show us what it is.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607144/sql-left-outer-join-with-where-clause

Comment: @TabAlleman Please see the edited version. I've mentioned the actual scenario.

Comment: Is time you show us some sample data current and expected output. We are wasting our time trying to guest what you need

Comment: @Vimal based on your edit, Juan Carlos' answer should solve your problem.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Please see the edited version above, hope it clarifies.

Comment: You only post map data, where is the view data? Also you said the problem is when map doesnt have data. but here map have data still isnt clear if reproduce the problem

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Please see the query carefully, the view is created itself from the Map table. The query is broken into two parts to reduce the data for two different dates.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: ok, let me take a look again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Conditional Aggregation to calculate the data for each desire date.

**[SQL DEMO](https://rextester.com/WNPPF9428)**

```
with myView as ( 
    Select mp.Id, 
           sum( CASE WHEN mp.bizDate='22-Jan-2019' 
                     THEN mp.Quantity
                     ELSE 0 
                END ) counts,
           sum( CASE WHEN mp.bizDate='25-Jan-2019' 
                     THEN mp.Quantity
                     ELSE 0 
                END ) quantity    
    from Map mp       
    group by mp.Id
)    
SELECT mv.Id, 
       counts,
       counts - quantity
FROM myView mv;
```

Comment: The problem with the first one is if myView has some rows which Map doesn't, it will not show them as well. I need the rows in either case. e.g. myView has 3 records, Map has 2 records, I need total 5 records and vice versa.

Comment: Check the demo Here you can see the difference Now need to understand what you have on the sum.  Because in your example you said A need substract 300, but on your data A doesnt have any rows for that date. Can you elaborate what you want there?

Comment: Ohh nevermind I sort the data and found the 300. Let me add the other part

Comment: Done check the demo.

Answer (score 1):

if you want always retrieve data use FULL OUTER JOIN

```
with myView as (Select t.tuneId, t.name from Tune t where <someCondition>)

Select m.name, mv.name from Map m 
FULL OUTER JOIN myView mv ON 
m.id=mv.tuneID where <someCondition>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Since Map has no data in it, m.id=mv.tuneID join fails and that's why it doesn't return the result.

Comment: @Vimal - Please make sure that your *someCondition* does not turn the OUTER JOIN into INNER, since NULL is not equal to anything, including another NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the structure of the code a little bit, by splitting the conditions.

Basically, if you are concerned that `MyView` has no rows, then:

```
with myView as (
      Select t.tuneId, t.name
      from Tune t
      where <someCondition>
    )
select m.name, mv.name
from Map m left join
     myView mv 
     on m.id = mv.tuneID and
        <conditions on myView>
where <conditions not on myView> ;
```

If `map` might have no rows, then the roles are reversed:

```
with myView as (
      Select t.tuneId, t.name
      from Tune t
      where <someCondition>
    )
select m.name, mv.name
from myView mv left join
     Map m
     on m.id = mv.tuneID and
        <conditions on map>
where <conditions not on map> ;
```

Comment: I need this two separate piece of code into one single query